# Zero out portion of multidim numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, numpy

I have an numpy array with dimensions (200, 200, 3). It is an RGB image.

I also have the (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) coordinates of a region of this image that I would like to set to zero. This region should be zero in all three channels.

I can of course solve this with a loop, but that would be wasteful.

Is there a simple way to mask the array using numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array slicing. If `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` are the indices of area of the array you want to set to zero, then:

```
a[xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax,:] = 0.
```

Comment: Are there any more efficient ways to zero a central section than array slicing?